# Where does raw geoip data come from?

Tags: geolocation

*This question is a general version of a more specific question [asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216198/how-or-where-does-foursquare-gets-its-geodata-from?rq=1).  However, those answers were unusable.*

**Question:** What is the raw source for geoIP data?

Many websites will tell me where my IP is, but they all appear to be using databases from fewer than 5 companies (most are using a database from MaxMind).  These companies offer limited free versions of their databases, but I'm trying to determine what they're using for their source data?

- I've tried using Linux/Unix commands such as ping, traceroute, dig, whois, etc., but they don't provide predictably accurate information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Preamble: I believe this is actually a very valid question for SO website as understanding how such things work is important to understanding how such datasets can be used in software. However the answer to this question is rather complex and full of historical remarks.

First - it is worth mentioning that there is NO unified raw geoip data. Such thing just does not exist. Second - the data for this comes from multiple resources and often is not reliable and/or outdated.

To understand how that comes to be one need to know how Internet came into existence and spread around the world. Short summary is below:

1. IANA is a global [non-profit] organization which manages assignment of IP blocks to regional organizations: https://www.iana.org/numbers This happens upon request and regional organization requests specified block size
2. Regional organizations may assign those IP blocks to either ISP directly or to country level sub-organizations (who would assign that to ISP then).
3. ISP assigns IP addresses to local branches etc.

From above you can easily see that:

1. There is no single body which is responsible for IP block assignment to this or that location
2. Decisions how to (and whether to) release information about which IP belongs to which location are not taken uniformly and instead each organizations decides how to (and whether do it at all) release that information

All of above creates a whole lot of mess. It takes a lot of dedication and long time to obtain, aggregate and sort this data. And this is why most up-to-date and detailed geoip datasets are [commercial commodity](https://www.maxmind.com/en/geoip2-country-database).

Whoever takes on a challenge of building their own dataset should be able to obtain this information directly from end users (ISPs), because higher level organizations do not know to which location each IP address will be assigned. Higher level organizations only `distribute` IP blocks among applicants (and keep some reserve for faster processing) and it is a lowest level organizations who decide which location gets which IP address and they are not obligated to release this information publicly.

**UPD:**
To start building your own dataset you can begin with [this list of blocks and how they are assigned](https://www.iana.org/assignments/ipv4-address-space/ipv4-address-space.xhtml)

Comment: @JBH JFYI - there are free versions of the dataset, but somewhat outdated and not 100% reliable. So you needn’t build your own geoip db yourself either.